# Joining a transaction fact table to a periodic snapshot table in SQL using the nearest date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift on AWS and I have two tables, the first is a list of transactions like so:

| cust_ID | order_date | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022/05/01 | A |
| 101 | 2022/05/01 | A |
| 100 | 2022/05/05 | B |
| 101 | 2022/05/07 | B |

The second is a snapshot table which has customer attributes for each customer at a specific point in time. Though the second table has rows for most dates, it doesn't have rows for every customer at every date.

| cust_ID | as_of_date | favourite_colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022/05/01 | blue |
| 100 | 2022/05/02 | red |
| 100 | 2022/05/05 | green |
| 100 | 2022/05/07 | red |
| 101 | 2022/05/01 | blue |
| 101 | 2022/05/04 | red |
| 101 | 2022/05/05 | green |
| 101 | 2022/05/08 | yellow |

How can I join the tables such that the transaction table has the customer attributes either on the date of the order itself, or if the transaction date is not available in table 2, at the nearest available date before the transaction?

An example of the desired output would be:

| cust_ID | order_date | product | Favourite_colour | as_of_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022/05/01 | A | blue | 2022/05/01 |
| 101 | 2022/05/01 | A | blue | 2022/05/01 |
| 100 | 2022/05/05 | B | green | 2022/05/05 |
| 101 | 2022/05/07 | B | green | 2022/05/05 |

Joining by cust_ID and order_date = as_of_date doesn't work due to edge cases where the order_date/id combination is not in the second table.

I've also tried something like:

```
with snapshot as (
SELECT 
  row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cust_ID ORDER BY as_of_date DESC) as row_number,
  cust_ID,
  favourite_color,
  as_of_date

FROM table2 t2

INNER JOIN table1 t1
 ON t1.cust_ID = t2.cust_ID
 AND t2.as_of_date <= t1.order_date

)
SELECT * FROM snapshot
WHERE row_number = 1
```

However, this doesn't handle cases where the same customer has multiple transactions in table 1. When I check the count of the resulting table, the number of distinct cust_IDs is the same as count(*) so it seems like the resulting table is only retaining one transaction per customer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using your provided table inputs, I tested this solution in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUb9TDcUd32WRyNafsMYfm/0) and it works for your desired output.

```sql
    with my_cte AS (
    select *,
           row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id, order_date ORDER BY as_of_date desc) ranked
      from transactions
 left join attribs using (cust_id)
     where as_of_date <= order_date
 )
 
 select cust_id, order_date, product, favorite_color, as_of_date
  from my_cte
  where ranked  = 1
order by order_date, cust_id;
```

Comment: This approach works well for small to medium sized datasets.  However the looped join can explode for very large data and since the OP is using Redshift this is a possibility.  If this is the case a UNION ALL approach will yield faster results - I wrote up a similar solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097833/find-the-next-oldest-row-in-redshift/65099643#65099643